# Change grub default option based on time

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, configuration

I tried to change the 00_header in grub to set a different default option in the menu if a certain condition is satisfied. If I am booting my computer before a specific time, the default option should be something else.

This is what I have done so far:

```
regexp --set hour "([0-9]{2})\:" `date`
if [ $hour -lt 9 ]; then
  set default="Windows 10"
fi
```

The regexp works (if I manually put the date as it comes out from `date`. However, the bottleneck is that the statement `date` is not replaced with the output of the command, but rather remains exactly what it is (`date`). I tried to google how to have the output of a grub command within a variable, but I had no luck.

Does anybody know how this could be achieved?

Thank you very much in advace.

Comment: I'd recommend to add such customizations to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and make sure this file is executable. `00_header` will be overridden when the grub package recieves an upgrade to a newer version. If you want to keep  it in `00_header`, the [answer of @ob2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311960/590937) looks promising.

Comment: If using description as default boot, it must match exactly to grub's entry like 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sdb1)'. Best to copy & paste from your grub.cfg. You can change description in 40_custom and use that as default if desired. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Specific_Entries The date command looks like it is more for setting system date. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf  Maybe boot, check time & reboot if needed into desired system.

Comment: Regarding 40_custom is a good idea. My windows entry is exactly “Windows 10” :-) my problem is how to get the output of (grub shell) date command

Comment: Found [this interesting link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/grub-reading-bios-date-time-for-conditional-boot-preferences-755024/).

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, the scripts under `/etc/grub.d` are not applied unless you run the command `update-grub`.
- The second problem is that result of those script should be an output to stdout that will be appended to grub.cfg, so you should have command like echo.
- The third problem is that grub has it's own language. While you can use condition like if, you cannot run bash command like date and as far as I know, their is no way to get date from grub embedded shell.

Basically, I'm afraid there is no way to achieve what you are expecting.

Edit : my bad, in that case, your script should look like that (not checked the syntax of grub as I'm not so friendly)

```
cat << EOF
regexp --set hour "([0-9]{2})\:" `date`
if [ $hour -lt 9 ]; then
  set default="Windows 10"
fi
EOF
```

Comment: I think you totally misunderstood my point. Changes in grub.cfg are not persistent. As I am testing my solution, grub sees those changes until I run update grub. What you suggest is nothing new to me. Lastly, as reported by gnu, grub shelll DOES CONTAIN a date command. All I have done works almost perfectly (homework try yourself), except that grub shell does not eval commands in ‘’ as bash would.